# Writing to MIDI file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, midi

I have been trying to find a way to write to a MIDI file using the C# MIDI Toolkit. However, I am constantly running into problems with time synchronization. The resulting MIDI file is always off beat. More precisely, it has correct rhythm in relation to itself, but when imported into a sequencer, it does not seem to contain any tempo information (which is understandable, since I never specify it from within my program). There is no documentation on how to do this.

I am using the following code to insert notes into a track.

```
public const int NOTE_LENGTH = 32;

private static void InsertNote(Track t, int pitch, int velocity, int position, int duration, int channel)
{
    ChannelMessageBuilder builder = new ChannelMessageBuilder();
    builder.Command = ChannelCommand.NoteOn;
    builder.Data1 = pitch;
    builder.Data2 = velocity;
    builder.MidiChannel = channel;
    builder.Build();
    t.Insert(position * NOTE_LENGTH, builder.Result);
    builder.Command = ChannelCommand.NoteOff;
    builder.Build();
    t.Insert((position + duration) * NOTE_LENGTH, builder.Result);
}
```

I am sure the notes themselves are okay, since the resulting output is audible, but has no tempo information. How do I enter tempo information into the `Sequence` object that contains my tracks?

Comment: How did you configure the `Sequence`?

Comment: No configuration. I just instantiated an object of its class, like so: `Sequence seq = new Sequence()` and then added to it. The constructor does not provide much and the attributes aren't well documented.

Comment: Aren't the properties the same as in SMF files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled upon an answer by brute-force trying: the `NOTE_LENGTH` should be evenly devisable by 3.